# How to rollback software updates?

Tags: 14.04, grub2, updates

I am having some difficulty with recent software updates and this is not the first time.

By pressing the shift key on startup I can (usually) get the grub menu but when I choose "advanced options" it only shows 2 options:
3.13.0-24 and 3.13.0-24 (recovery mode)
whereas I understood it should show previous kernel versions.

I already stick to only LTS versions of Ubuntu.
What is a safe way to accept updates in future please?
How can I install only the most tested updates?
I would like to be able to easily roll them back if they cause problems. In other words I am looking for the Linux equivalent of making a Windows system restore point. 
Maybe I should never accept updates but wait until the next LTS version and then upgrade?

Comment: Thanks for your quick comment but the top answer in the possible duplicate says "Simply boot an older kernel" but that does not appear to be simple as I do not have the option on my grub menu as far as I can see.

Comment: Have you tried searching how to do that? Essentially, there is no feature for roll back currently.

Comment: Which channels are you using to get updates? In your sources.list, do you have `proposed` enabled? You can install an older kernel version if it is still available in the repository.

Comment: @Tim: OK thanks as I suspected from other answers here there still is not a straightforward built in rollback feature. So now that is confirmed I can stop looking for one. I have not answered my own question as, being new here, I am not sure whether Tim will get kudos if he writes it as an answer. If there is some proposed feature it would be good to have a link in the answer if there is some kind of voting option to support it.

Comment: @Muru: I am not sure how to check sources.list but I was pretty surprised when I looked at "Install updates from" to see "Unsupported updates" ticked. So I have unticked that thanks.

Comment: I suppose that should be enough for now. Considering how strict you were going to be, you could enable just -security and -updates. For future reference: `grep proposed /etc/apt/sources.list`.